# How to improve processing time for queries that use CONNECT BY and LEVEL clause

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I was wondering if there's a way to re-write the following oracle SQL script to get a better processing time. This current version is very slow and wouldn't work the larger dataset that I'm working with.

I'm trying to assign a number to each customer based on how many years they have been with the business. And I need it to return the each customer with their start year and then count up to the present. I've tried to explain it below.

For a customer that has been with the business for 5 years I want the script to return the following

| Customer code | Year Number | Number of years |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUST1 | 2018 | 0 |
| CUST1 | 2019 | 1 |
| CUST1 | 2020 | 2 |
| CUST1 | 2021 | 3 |
| CUST1 | 2022 | 4 |
| CUST1 | 2023 | 5 |

I'm trying to use CONNECT BY and LEVEL for this but it's taking too long.

```
YEARS AS 
(
  SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, (MIN_YR+LEVEL-1) AS YR_NUM, ((MIN_YR+LEVEL-1) - MIN_YR) AS YRS
  FROM
(
  SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM MIN_DT) MIN_YR , '2023' AS CUR_YR
  FROM
  (
    SELECT REV.CUSTOMER_CODE, MIN(REV.ORDER_DATE) AS MIN_DT
    FROM REVENUE_TABLE REV 
    JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS ACC ON REV.CUSTOMER_CODE = ACC.CUSTOMER_CODE
    GROUP BY REV.CUSTOMER_CODE
  )
)
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CUR_YR-MIN_YR
)

SELECT * FROM YEARS
```

I've used CONNECT BY and LEVEL clauses to generate a number for each customer which would represent the number of years with the business. The script is working but it would take too long for it to be useable. I let the script run for around 4 hours but it didn't finish running. The data volume is too high for this to complete.

Comment: Do you really need JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS ACC ON REV.CUSTOMER_CODE = ACC.CUSTOMER_CODE? I think not. Try and see how that performs without the join in the innermost query. I think this is the main reason for poor performance.

Comment: Yes, I do need the customer details table as it is filtering the number of customers to a smaller subset. The revenue table has a lot more customers which I don't need to include.
I did try running it without the customer table and it is till very slow, returning only 100 rows every 15 seconds. 
The recursive query completed in around 6 minutes for over 200,000 customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the innermost query, there is probably no use including the customer_details table - you are not using anything in it.  Its only possible use is to filter out revenue elements that are not in your customer_details table, but I really doubt you are trying to do that.

A more succinct approach would be to use a recursive CTE that starts with the earliest date for each customer, then rolls it forward by a year each time until it equals the current year.

```
With Recursive Years AS (
    SELECT REV.CUSTOMER_CODE, Year(MIN(REV.ORDER_DATE)) AS Year_Number
    FROM REVENUE_TABLE REV 
    GROUP BY REV.CUSTOMER_CODE
  UNION ALL
    Select CUSTOMER_CODE, Year_Number+1
    From Years
    Where Year_Number < Year(Current_Date)
)
Select * from Years
```

Now you can join the rest of your tables to that result or do whatever else you need with it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Chris! I really need to start learning about recursive functions and start using them. 
This was exactly what I was looking for. I was using the customer details table to filter the customers to a smaller subset. I've added that table back to the query. I also needed a count for each year starting at zero and incrementing by 1 which I've also added to the query. 
Thanks again! This was really helpful!